# looping function giving error of "return’ with a value, in function returning void"

Tags: c++, c, kernel

original code is

```
#define MAX_FRAMES 10000
#define MS_BETWEEN_FRAMES CONFIG_FB_MSM_LOGO_ANIMATE_FPS

int load_565rle_image(char *filename, bool bf_supported);
struct delayed_work rle_animate_work;

static void load_565rle_animate(struct work_struct *work)
{
    int i, ret = 0, bf_supported = 0;
    char filename [20];
    struct fb_info *info = registered_fb[0];
    set_fs(KERNEL_DS);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Starting kernel boot animation\n");
    for (i = 1; i < MAX_FRAMES; i++) {
        sprintf(filename, "/res/bootlogo/%d.rle", i);
        ret = load_565rle_image(filename, bf_supported);
        sys_unlink(filename);
        if (ret == -ENOENT)
            break;
        info->fbops->fb_open(info, 0);
        info->fbops->fb_pan_display(&info->var, info);
        msleep(MS_BETWEEN_FRAMES);
    }
}

static int __init logo_animate_init(void)
{
    INIT_DELAYED_WORK(&rle_animate_work, load_565rle_animate);
    schedule_delayed_work(&rle_animate_work, 5 * HZ);
    return 0;
}

static void __exit logo_animate_exit(void)
{
    return;
}
```

this make kernel logo animated, by loading series of *.rle image continuously ie 1.rle>2.rle>3.rle>4.rle>5.rle and so on.

the way it was originally written is to stop loading those images when it reaches end of image filename, ie if last filename is 5.rle, it stops and halted there.
basicaly what i'm trying to do now is looping, when it reaches last file (5.rle) it'll continue loading from the beginning again (1.rle).

so i added CONFIG_FB_MSM_LOGO_ANIMATE_LOOP

```
static void load_565rle_animate(struct work_struct *work)
{
    int i, ret = 0, bf_supported = 0;
    char filename [20];
    struct fb_info *info = registered_fb[0];
    set_fs(KERNEL_DS);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Starting kernel boot animation\n");
    for (i = 1; i < MAX_FRAMES; i++) {
        sprintf(filename, "/res/bootlogo/%d.rle", i);
        ret = load_565rle_image(filename, bf_supported);
        sys_unlink(filename);
        if (ret == -ENOENT)
#ifdef CONFIG_FB_MSM_LOGO_ANIMATE_LOOP
            return ret;
#else
            break;
#endif
        info->fbops->fb_open(info, 0);
        info->fbops->fb_pan_display(&info->var, info);
        msleep(MS_BETWEEN_FRAMES);
    }
}
```

but when the CONFIG_FB_MSM_LOGO_ANIMATE_LOOP is enable, it give compile error of 'warning: ‘return’ with a value, in function returning void [enabled by default]'
which halted the compile process. any thoughts?

Comment: Why do you declare it `void` if you want to return a value?

Answer (score 0):

```
#ifdef CONFIG_FB_MSM_LOGO_ANIMATE_LOOP
            return ret;
 #else
        break;
 #endif
```

this is beeing preprocessed by preprocessr and result in returning `int ret` from your function when CONFIG_FB_MSM_LOGO_ANIMATE_LOOP is defined. So

> ‘return’ with a value, in function returning void

seems to be quite reasonable hint.

solution:
change also function returned type then or change it to:

```
#ifdef `CONFIG_FB_MSM_LOGO_ANIMATE_LOOP`
            return;
 #else
        break;
 #endif
```